# Symfony 3.4.0 PDO Driver not found even though they are installed

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, cloud9-ide

My problem is that whatever I do I can't seem to generate entities with the command :

`php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import AppBundle xml`

The error I get everytime is a classic:[Pics of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcRDm.png)

I already put the good database parameters in parameters.yml. The file config.yml is ok too.

My Php version is :

```
PHP 7.0.26 (cli)
```

My php.ini in my app folder already contains :

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

I already installed all the php7 required.

The result of the command :

```
php -i
```

contains :

```
PDO
    PDO support => enabled
    PDO drivers =>
```

I don't know what to do now, I can't seem to find the origin of the problem.
I have to add that I'm doing all this on Cloud9.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Does "php -i | grep mysql" reveal anything useful?

Comment: @Cerad Nothing, should it ?

Comment: It means you don't have the basic mysql interface installed.  I don't use cloud9 so I can give you any details but check the docs for using mysql with php.

Comment: @Cerad Then I don't know what to do because when I want to install those basic packages I get that they're already there. How can that be ? Where is the incoherence ?

`php7.0-mysql is already the newest version.`

`php-mysql is already the newest version.`

Comment: All I can suggest is that you verify the problem by trying to connect directly to a database outside of Symfony: https://community.c9.io/t/connecting-php-to-mysql/1606 And assuming you get some sort of "unknown function mysqli_connect" error then post a question with a cloud 9 tag.

Comment: I can totally connect to the DB outside symfony, I actually run a perfectly fine phpmyadmin that allowed me to create my tables.

Comment: And can you connect using a pdo connection?  You are certain you did not misspell pdo_mysql in your driver config?

Comment: I can already say that I didn't misspell it because the error isn't that the driver is unknown. It's that it can not fink it. I'll try making a pdo connection in plain php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end my partner reinstalled everything from scratch.

The problem seemed to be an incompatibility between the php version used and the symphony version used.

Thank you all for your time !

Answer (score 1):

There could be at least two reasons:

- `pdo_mysql` is not configured in php.ini for cli
- `pdo_mysql` is not installed at all

Last time I was using phpmyadmin, it was using `mysql_*`, instead of `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should execute, to see if you have all the required dependencies.

```
php bin/symfony_requirements
```

Also referre to http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/requirements.html